# Pause script for a set amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that scrolls to the top of an element (rather than just jumping there), but I need to offer an option to pause execution while the scroll event is taking place.

The reason for this is that further events in the script (i.e. showing a `Dialog`), are causing the animation to abandon and instead the page is just jumping to the element.

I know that `.animate()` offers functions for `complete()`, etc. but this is no good as the `smoothScroll` is called from multiple locations, and some actions do not require the function. Besides, it seems very impractical to split code in to lots of little mini-functions just to satisfy this requirement.

I've tried using `setTimeout()`, but sadly it looks as though execution is carried out around it, with only the code declared within it waiting to execute.

Is what I require possible with JS? Thanks.

```
function smoothScrool(target, duration, pause){

    /** Ensure that the parameterse are set */
    if(!target.length) return false;
    duration = (typeof duration !== 'number') ? 1000 : duration;
    pause = (typeof pause !== 'boolean') ? true : pause;

    /** Start the animation */
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, duration);

    /** Pause until the animation is complete (if required) */
    if(pause){
        setTimeout(function(){
            return true
        }, duration);
    }

}
```

Comment: Adding jQuery tag to your question will be well suited

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible for a script to wait for a certain amount of time - JavaScript is executed synchronously, so the browser would block for that time.

So what you need to do is to move all the code after the `if(pause)` into a second function `afterPause()`. Now you can:

```
if(pause) {
  setTimeout(afterPause, duration); // wait
} else {
  afterPause(); // do it now
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as mentioned that is not possible in this case. `smoothScroll()` is called from multiple locations within my script, and before some of the calls I check which action the user is carrying out as scrolling may not be necessary. Therefore refactoring my code would mean that some actions cannot access what they need.

Comment: Please add all the necessary information to your question. Leaving out important details won't get you the answer you want.

Comment: You omitted the code in the actions. If you gave us everything, we might give you advice how to change the code in the actions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is 'throttling', a system whereby execution of a function is rate-limited. Here's how to achieve it:

```
// Create a closure to execute immediately and contain the throttle state
var smoothScroll = ( function throttleClosure(){
    // A throttled function won't run, so set it to false by default
    var throttled = false;

    // Throttling prevents execution, and also sets a timeout after which to unthrottle
    function throttle( duration ){
        setTimeout( function unthrottle(){
            throttled = false;
        }, duration );
    }

    // Return the function to assign to the parent scope's `smoothScroll` variable
    return function smoothScroll(target, duration, pause){
        /** Ensure that the parameterse are set */
        if(!target.length) return false;
        duration = (typeof duration !== 'number') ? 1000 : duration;
        pause    = (typeof pause !== 'boolean')   ? true : pause;

        // If the function is throttled, don't execute
        if( throttled ){
            return false;
        }

        // throttle if necessary… 
        if( pause ){
            throttle( duration );
        }

        /** Start the animation */
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, duration);
    }
}() );
```